# TensorFlow custom loss function not specified correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, subclass, loss-function

I’m experimenting on building a ML model in python using TensorFlow. I have designed my program as shown below, and it “technically” runs the epochs etc., but the results I get are absolute nonsense.

I’m pretty sure, it has to do with the custom_loss function that is actually not handling what I really want the program to do. Basically, I would like the program to back out estimates of the values of ALPHA, BETA which are unobserved/unknown values in the data set, and where I have Z and W given as numerical values in the data set. The X data frame containing the explanatory numeric and encoded variables, should explain ALPHA, BETA, along with the deterministic relationship Z = ALPHA * BETA * W.

To provide a concrete example, say that I have an observation Z = 200 and W = 1000, then a linear combination ALPHA * BETA that solves Z_PRED = 200 could be 0.1 * 2. I have about 42.000 observations in my full data set.

MY PROGRAM AS-IS:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

# Loading the dataset
merged_df4 = pd.read_csv('merged_df3.csv')

# Initializing alpha, beta
np.random.seed(1)  # Set a seed for reproducibility
merged_df4['ALPHA'] = np.random.uniform(0.0001, 0.9999, len(merged_df4))
merged_df4['BETA'] = np.random.uniform(0.0001, 0.9999, len(merged_df4))

# Separating the independent and dependent variables
X = merged_df4.drop(['ALPHA','BETA', 'Z', 'W'], axis=1).values.astype(float)
y = merged_df4[['ALPHA', 'BETA','Z','W']].values.astype(float)

# Scaling
scaler_X = RobustScaler()
scaler_y = RobustScaler()
X_scaled = scaler_X.fit_transform(X)
y_scaled = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)

# Splitting the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y_scaled, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Custom loss function
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    Z = y_true[:, 2] # Extract Z from y_true
    W = y_true[:, 3]  # Extract W from y_true

    Z_PRED = y_pred[:, 0] * y_pred[:, 1] * W

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Z - Z_PRED))
    return loss

# Create a custom model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)  # Output layer with 2 targets (ALPHA, BETA)
])

# Compile the model with custom loss
learning_rate = 0.0001  # Adjust the learning rate here
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=custom_loss)

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=1)

# Evaluate the model
y_pred_scaled = model.predict(X_test)

# Joining columns 0 and 1 from y_pred_scaled with columns 2 and 3 from y_scaled
y_all_scaled = np.concatenate((y_pred_scaled[:, :2], y_test[:, 2:]), axis=1)

# Inverse scaling for ALPHA and BETA
y_pred_unscaled = np.copy(y_all_scaled)  # Create a copy for unscaled predictions
y_pred_unscaled[:, :4] = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_pred_unscaled[:, :4])

# Create a DataFrame with predictions
df_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred_unscaled, columns=['ALPHA', 'BETA', 'Z_PRED', 'W'])
```

I have some idea, that it could be a way to solve the issue by using subclasses with non-trainable weights, and I have tried to implement that in my program in various ways without success though.

But, if there is a work around just sticking with my custom_loss approach, that would be fine too, as I like to keep the model as simple as possible.